# Cannot parse JWT by new version of jjwt library

Tags: java, jwt, jjwt

I've updated jjwt to version 0.12.3. I use a keystore PKCS12 to sign jwt and validate it. But now I'm getting errror: ***JWS verification key must be either a SecretKey (for MAC algorithms) or a PublicKey (for Signature algorithms).*** Everything works fine on the version 0.9.1

```
private static Key getKey() throws Exception {
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keystore.load(GenerateValidateKey.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.p12"), "test".toCharArray());
        Enumeration aliases = keystore.aliases();
        String keyAlias = "";
        while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
            keyAlias = (String) aliases.nextElement();
        }
        return keystore.getKey(keyAlias, "test".toCharArray());
    }
```

```
Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
            claims.put("aud", "test");
            claims.put("sub", "test");

String token = Jwts.builder().signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256, getKey())
                    .setSubject("test")
                    .setExpiration(Date.from(expiration.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()))
                    .setIssuedAt(Date.from(now.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()))
                    .setClaims(claims)
                    .compact();
```

```
Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                                .setSigningKey(getKey())
                                .requireAudience("test")
                                .build()
                                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                                .getBody();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
var parser = Jwts.parser().verifyWith(getKey()).build();
return  parser.parseSignedClaims(token).getPayload();
```